# Angular Observable<Model> object is always empty

Tags: angular, angular2-observables, rxjs-observables

I am trying to assign value received from get request to a model object in angular. However the object is always empty. Following is my code, what am I doing wrong?

**Model class**

```
export class UserModel{
 username:string='';
 displayName:string='';
}
```

**home.component.ts class**

```
constructor(private service:UserService){
 this.getUser();
}

getUser(){
 this.service.getUserModel('johnp').subscribe(res => this.user = res as UserModel);
  // **THIS OBJECT IS STILL EMPTY**
  console.log(this.user)  
}
```

**user.service.ts class**

```
getUserModel(username:string):Observable<UserModel>{
 return this.http.get<UserModel>(this.url+'/getUser/'+username)
  .pipe(
    map(usermodel=>{
     return usermodel
    }),
   catchError(this.handleError)
  );
 }

private handleError(error:HttpErrorResponse){
 console.log(error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When execution hits `this.service.getUserModel('johnp').subscribe(res => this.user = res as UserModel);` it will fire the request and move on to the next thing while the subscription completes in the background. It will not wait for the subscription to complete before moving on to `console.log(this.user)` which will result in the object being null as the subscription has not yet completed and assigned the value from the response.

To test this you can do the following:

```
this.service.getUserModel('johnp').subscribe(res => {
    this.user = res as UserModel; 
    console.log("inside subscription", this.user); 
});
```

If that returns a `null` as well then your service is not returning an object

Comment: if I console.log inside the function I can see the values which means my service is working fine.

Comment: Any additional processing you need to do on this.user will have to happen inside the subscription then otherwise it will always be null

Comment: Problem is when I try to display value in html from user object it comes as null.

Comment: This sounds change detection related then. Try wrapping the user object in a *ngIf null check in the html

Comment: ngIf null check indicates that variable is not null but empty.

Comment: Changed method to : this.service
    .getUserModel('jonhp')
    .subscribe((data:UserModel) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.user= data;
    }); Now the object is not empty but when I try to show value on html like {{user.username}} it comes up as blank.

Comment: Further investigation shows the problem is assigning value from json to object, the plain json shows with value when printed on html.